# Lambda Not Loading Cryptography Shared Library

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm using the cryptography library in AWS Lambda. I've compiled the package using pip in an Amazon Linux VM. I have uploaded the package as a layer. Either way, every time I call the library, I have an error which is not descriptive at all:

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libffi-ae16d830.so.6.0.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, the error is not about not finding the lib, is another shared module which I haven't been able to find.

Here's an example of the code I'm trying to execute on Lambda:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

password_provided = "test123" 
password = password_provided.encode() 
salt = b'test_' 
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
    algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
    length=32,
    salt=salt,
    iterations=100000,
    backend=default_backend()
)
key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password)) 


message = "message from db".encode()

f = Fernet(key)
encrypted = f.encrypt(message)

print(encrypted)

f = Fernet(key)
decrypted = f.decrypt(encrypted)

print(decrypted.decode("utf-8"))
```

It's not the first time I've compiled a library to work on AWS Lambda, but in this case even I compile the cryptography lib. What should I add or change?

**Edit:**
I've found out the library was missing in the zip file I've created, as is inside a hidden folder. I zipped using '.' instead of '*'  but now I'm running with a new problem: When I run the lambda, I get this:

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /opt/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_constant_time.so: undefined symbol: PyInt_FromLong
```

any idea?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but it looks like your compiled library contains an SO file which is dependent by libffi-ae16d830.so - maybe check if you can include it in your package in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same issue, while zipping I forgot to include the hidden files(.libs_cffi_backend) in the site-packages.
After Including it, I didn't see this error.

Answer (score 0):

As the library you're using requires native libraries, you have to pack the native .so files as well with the layer. I ran into a similar issue while trying to run wkhtmltopdf on aws lambda.

The binaries for the library has to be compiled in the same environment as a lambda instance. Lambda gets booted up using AWS Linux.

You can either boot up an EC2 running AmazonLinux or use docker, easiest way is to boot up a docker container.

```
$ sudo docker run -it amazonlinux bash
```

Now you need to download/unpack all .so files into a directory then zip it. Also, make sure to keep all .so files inside a folder called lib inside the zip. After zipping, the zip should look something similar to this:

```
.
├── lib
│   ├── libcrypto.so.10
│   ├── libcrypto.so.1.0.2k
│   ├── libfontconfig.so.1
│   ├── libfontconfig.so.1.7.0
.......
```

Then you can just zip it and upload it as a layer. It will be uploaded to /opt/ in your Lambda Container. AWS looks for library files under /opt/lib amongst [many other locations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html).

The challenging part for you would be to figure out how to get all the required .so files in order for your dependency to run properly.

Comment: Should the lib folder with the .so files be in the root of the layer zip?

Answer (score 0):

Previously I manually packed the archive, deployed with `aws cloudformation deploy`, and had the same problem. I then switched to using `sam build --use-container` and it worked. My suspicion is that it works because SAM uses a specific container. This is the container it uses: https://gallery.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.7