# "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, pip, aws-lambda-layers

I have created a lambda layer with the following python packages using pip3:
`google-cloud-texttospeech` and
`azure-cognitiveservices-speech`

When I use this layer with python3.8 lambda function, I get the error saying,

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

I removed the azure-cognitiveservices-speech package and the layer works fine with lambda. This means that the culprit is the `azure-cognitiveservices-speech` package. I couldn't find a way to solve the problem.

Any kind of help will be grately appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to install the package manually on your system and package the same with your lambda zip file as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/setup-platform?tabs=dotnet%2Cwindows%2Cjre%2Cbrowser&pivots=programming-language-python#prerequisites)

Once installed you can package your python code and the .so files together and upload to AWS lambda. The folder structure for your reference should look like this.

```
myawesomefunction.py
libasound.so.2
```

Comment: I've tried this and still I get the same error. I copied /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2 to a folder containing the function, created a zip and uploaded.

Comment: I do have some stuff for internal development and this structure works. Plus in this question[lambda-not-loading-cryptography-shared-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508626/lambda-not-loading-cryptography-shared-library) described the same approach and it works. It might be because of the path or different os,

Comment: I used the amazon linux from aws.

Comment: can you download the zip and check if the shared object present in the package? Even official amazon [solution](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-linux-binary-package/) suggests the similar approach.

Comment: As per the document we have to copy /usr/lib64/*. Is it so? I had just copied the libasound.so.2 file

Comment: yeah give it a shot, what I do is simply package the whole folder in lambda deployment package.

Comment: I managed to do it. I basically copied all `*.so*` files from /usr/lib64/ and added into my lambda package.

Is there a way to seperate these libraries from my main function? Maybe I can add them as another layer? I don't how to seperate it.

Comment: if I were you I would package the whole thing as a docker image and deploy the [lambda via docker image](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/)